How to fetch the keys from JSON column from list of tables in a database
SELECT 
    s.name  +'.'+ t.name AS Tablename,
    c.name AS ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.tables t
JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE 
    tp.name = 'nvarchar' 
    AND (c.max_length = -1 ) --or c.max_length =  '8000') -- JSON columns of type NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AND s.name NOT LIKE 'bireports' 
    AND t.name NOT LIKE '%_bk%' 
    AND t.name NOT LIKE '%_mcr_%' 
    AND t.name NOT LIKE '%_mmp_%'  
ORDER BY 
    s.name, t.name, c.name;

This query returns table name and JSON column name.
I need one more column in which the JSON column consists of the following keys
firstname, midilename, fullname, email, phone, dateofbirth

Sample output
tablename              Json columnname               keys

table1                    Jsoncolumn          firstname,lastname,email     

table2                    Jsoncolumn          phone,dob

There are no columns in JSON, it's just text. That text can contain arrays and dictionaries of key/value pairs. Nothing says that all the text values in a table will contain the same shape of objects, much less have the keys (not columns) you expect. It's even possible for a single text value to have an array of 10 objects and only the last one will have the keys you expect

Then you need to actually read the table column values, there's no metadata that exposes this information. Also, json is a flexible format, so keys can be different for every array row

In short, you'll have to query all the rows in all the matching tables to find out if they matching columns contain the keys you expect. Frankly, I suspect the database design is bad. If you care about specific columns you should have separate tables

This sounds like an XY problem. You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution (searching the database schema tables). When Y failed, you asked about it, not the real problem X. What's the actual problem? The query you posted doesn't find JSON columns at all, it finds text columns that don't match a pattern. Nothing says JSON text is only stored in nvarchar(max) columns

Does this answer your question? Comma separated results in SQL
